# Removing a Node Manager from WebLogic

Tags: java, weblogic

I've exported a template jar from our test server and want to set it up on my local VM.  I'd like to not use the Node Manager.  I started up the server using startWebLogic.sh, but the managed servers won't start because they are associated with a domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you attempt to start a managed server through the admin console, it will use the nodemanager.

If you do not want to use the nodemanager, you need to call the `startManagedWebLogic.sh` script instead. This will start the managed server in [independence mode](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/web.1111/e13708/failures.htm#START167). Either pass in the server name and admin server URL to the script or set the following in your environment first.

`export SERVER_NAME=name`

`export ADMIN_URL=http://your_admin_url:port`